# Embed vector graphics with animation into iOS native app

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, animation, vector

I'm looking for a way to display animated vector graphics in a native iOS application.

The artist draws a character in vector, and then import it into Flash and animate it.
Why exactly vector, but not sprites? Because the character has many stuff and animations. And if I use frame animation, I need to render all animation variants for all appearance variants. Skeletal sprite animation looks poorly.
Now I try solution from Adobe - Flash Toolkit for CreateJS.
I put the result in UIWebView. Everything seems to be working, I can replace vector elements by others and start animation for each element separately (that's what I need). But there is a performance problem, so I can't use more complicated vector graphics. And the solution looks like not native.

Maybe there is some other solution?

Comment: I Dont know Why people has not answered this? but need help too. So if Saintech, you have got some idea then Please share

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to using Starling ([Starling home page](http://gamua.com/starling/)), I found some interesting information that this may benefit from here: [flash-movieclip-converter-preserves-display-list-hierarchy](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/flash-movieclip-converter-preserves-display-list-hierarchy)

Also here are some GIT repos you can check out that might be helpful:
https://github.com/zenrobin/FlashMovieClipConverter
https://github.com/philippecapouillez/FlashMovieClipConverter

Hope that helps.